# Using SAML to authenticate user for a force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, authentication, saml, federated-authentication, delegated-authentication

We are building a force.com site application for a company. It will be used by the company's employees who will login into the application using the company's own login page (which uses their own authentication server).

Currently, the company uses [SAML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50ogFCF56qE) (Security Assertion Markup Language) as a single sign-on mechanism where the IDP (Identity Provider) is the company and the service provider is Salesforce. So their employees log in their Salesforce instances using a single sign on page which is maintained by the company.

The company wants the users to log in the force.com site application through this same system. I am confused on how to implement SAML with force.com site. Talking to them it seems they create a server cookie and a session at their backend and it is not sent to the browser as cookie or anything. So what do I check against for a successful login? Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_sites.htm&language=en) should be the approach you should be following. Force.com sites do support SSO using SAML.

> You need to provide the following info for your identity provider
>
> Organization ID
>
> Portal ID
>
> Sites URL
>
> The following must be added as attributes to the SAML assertion sent
>   from your identity provider:
>
> organization_id
>
> portal_id
>
> siteurl
>
> If you wanted to use SAML for Sites for when a service provider
>   initiates sign-on, you must first create a Visualforce page that
>   provides a redirect to your server. The following is an example:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
 <script>
     var PingSpURL = "https://my.pingserver.com:9031/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=salesforce.com.sp";
     var siteLoginPage = "&TargetResource={!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}siteLogin?startUrl={!$Site.OriginalUrl}";
     window.location = PingSpURL+siteLoginPage;
 </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So my service provider login will pass those 3 things to the IDP and after the IDP asserts the user correctly it will send a true/false flag to the service provider (my force.com site application) based on which I will let them in?

Comment: The SAML in my case is an IDP initiated login. I am confused about the "assertion".  Where do I look for organization_id or any other information sent through SAML? Is it part of request headers?